# Converting HSL to RBG

Tags: haskell, colors, rgb, hsl

I'm trying to convert some `HSL` value to `RBG` with Data.Colour module. Hackage doc said that `Hue` is always in the range 0-360. But there are now any ranges of `Saturation` and `Lightness` values. Are they in [0,100] or in [0,1] ranges?

I suppose that first variant is right, but seems like it is not.

```
λ> hsl 100 50 50
RGB {channelRed = 866.6666666666692, channelGreen = -2400.0, channelBlue = 2500.0}
```

Than I tried to use the range [0, 1] for both saturation and lightness.

```
λ> fmap truncate . (\(h,s,l) -> hsl h s l) $ (0,0,0)
RGB {channelRed = 0, channelGreen = 0, channelBlue = 0}
it :: RGB Integer
```

That why I'm start thinking that only `Saturation` should be a `Double` in `[0,1]`.

For example we have some color value in `HSL` format.

```
λ> let c = (34.0,0.54,68.0)
c :: (Double, Double, Double)
```

Than we convert it to `RGB` and truncate all values

```
λ> fmap truncate . (\(h,s,l) -> hsl h s l) $ c
RGB {channelRed = 31, channelGreen = 63, channelBlue = 104}
```

But `(31,63,104)::RGB` is `(214,54,26)::HSL` like [some online color-converters](http://serennu.com/colour/hsltorgb.php) said.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Bad enough they expect the hue in [0..360] rather than the IMO proper [0,2π[.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the package uses the range `[0, 1]` for both lightness and saturation, but note that it also uses this range for RGB values, and not `[0, 255]` as you seem to be assuming. Taking this into account, I get (almost) the expected values:

```
> fmap (truncate . (* 255)) $ hsl 214 0.54 0.26
RGB {channelRed = 30, channelGreen = 61, channelBlue = 102}
```

Comment: Best timing! But it is really unobvious to figured out that returning double value is actually `RGB`.

Answer (score 1):

So finally I've figured out that both `Saturation` and `Lightness` value should be in the [0,1] range.

```
λ> fmap (round . (255*)). (\(h,s,l) -> hsl h s l) $ (34.0,0.54,0.68)
RGB {channelRed = 217, channelGreen = 179, channelBlue = 129}
it :: RGB Integer
```

It makes a sense, because `(217,179,129)::RGB` value is equal to `(34,54,68)::HSL`.

So, maybe it would be helpful to add that constrains in the docs.

Comment: The package maintainer is Russell O'Connor.  His email is on the [package page](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/colour), I'm sure he would be happy to have your missing documentation report and fix it.